# Java, choose subsequence

Tags: java, string, vector, stringbuffer

I have a problem with a part of my program.

In the following code, there are 27 letters in our alphabet.

The aim is: for every repetition of the outer `for`, we take the last `n` characters of `text_generated`, and for every letter of the alphabet, we count the number of occurrences in `text_formatted` of the `n+1` characters obtained by adding the character to the last `n` characters of `text_generated`; then we choose the letter with the most occurrences and append it to `text_generated`.  The result I obtain is something like:

```
***aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

why?

The code:

```
        int index;
        int[] occurrences = new int[27];
        int count;
        for(int a = 0; a < m; a++){     // m is the number of characters the user wants to add              

            for(int b = 0; b < 27; b++){
                StringBuffer curr_word = new StringBuffer(text_generated.substring(text_generated.length()-n, text_generated.length()));
                count = 0;
                for(int c = 0; c <= text_formatted.length() -n-1;c++){
                    if(text_formatted.substring(c,c+n+1).equals(curr_word.append(array[b])))
                    count += 1;
                }
                occurrences[b] = count;
            }

            index = 0;
            for(int d = 1; d < 27; d++){
                if(occurrences[d] > occurrences[index])
                    index = d;
            }

            text_generated = text_generated.append(array[index]);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result that you get`***aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` and this loop

```
index = 0;
for(int d = 1; d < 27; d++){
  if(occurrences[d] > occurrences[index])
    index = d;
}
```

indicates that that the every item in the occurrences array is 0. This means that your algorithm defaults to appending `array[0]` to the `text_generated` string. This means that the problem is in this block

```
for(int c = 0; c <= text_formatted.length() -n-1;c++){
  if(text_formatted.substring(c,c+n+1).equals(curr_word.append(array[b])))
    count += 1;
}
```

Possible problems:

- The loop is never entered, `text_formatted.length() - n - 1` results in a negative value.
- The `if` always evaluates to `false`.

In both cases the problem is most likely related to the values of `n` and `text_formatted`.

Answer (score 3):

You always set your `index = 0`, so first letter in array[] is chosen, which always is `a`.

Comment: but the following instruction "for" controls if occurrences[d] > occurrences[index] for some d